# Listen to another rails actioncable server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, server, actioncable

In my case, I have one actioncable only server which is already running. 
I want to build another server that listen to my actioncable server, then my mobile application will listening to this new actioncable server.

Can I do that?

Comment: Seems like it's not supported with ActionCable - see https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/24931 However I think it is possible with other websocket libraries such as [em-websocket](https://github.com/igrigorik/em-websocket) (there are others if you google "websocket ruby"). You basically just need a library that can subscribe to messages from a given websocket URL, and you write the forwarding code yourself.

Comment: ok, i get it, thanks @maxpleaner